# Getting TSC frequency from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: linux, cpu

I want to know the TSC frequency on a Linux system. Reading from /proc/cpuinfo I get different frequencies in the lines "model name" and "cpu MHz". For example, in a core i7 with 4 HT Cores I got:

```
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz
cpu MHz     : 1600.000
```

Which is the correct TSC frequency? 3.4 GHz or 1.6 GHz?

I´m assuming only new processors, so variable TSC freq is not a problem.

Is "cpu MHz" the current frequency of the processor? I mean, Can this value change according to the CPU load?

Edited: I made a simple program that compute TSC frequency (using long times measured with time() ), and I got 3502 MHz (aproximately), in the 3.4 GHz machine. So either the Linux time() function is not very exact, or the TSC is faster than the claimed 3.4 GHz.

So, Does anybody knows if the /proc/cpuinfo is reliable?

Comment: Use Google: http://serverfault.com/questions/474151/why-does-proc-cpuinfo-show-contradicting-processor-speeds

Comment: @Nazar554 You found a question similar to mine, but not a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my server:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo  | grep "model name\|cpu MHz"
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8163 CPU @ 2.50GHz
cpu MHz         : 2699.804
```

2.50GHz is TSC frequency and 2699.804 is current frequency.

You can also use `turbostat` to get TSC frequency and current frequency.

> **Bzy_MHz** average clock rate while the CPU was not idle (ie. in "c0" state).
>
> **TSC_MHz** average MHz that the TSC ran during the entire interval.
>
> https://manpages.debian.org/testing/linux-cpupower/turbostat.8.en.html

```
$ sudo turbostat --interval 1
     CPU Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz CoreTmp  PkgTmp
       -       2    0.07    2671    2501      48      48
       0       4    0.15    2703    2502      44      46
      48       0    0.00    2644    2502
       1       3    0.13    2703    2502      44
      49       0    0.00    2569    2502
       2       1    0.05    2700    2502      45
      50       0    0.01    2670    2502
       3       1    0.05    2707    2502      44
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same problem under link below: measured tsc 3502 cpu frequency 3400Mhz

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/284137

Resolved by turning off automatic over-clocking in BIOS

Answer (score -2):

```
Is "cpu MHz" the current frequency of the processor?  I mean, Can this value change according to the CPU load?
```

Yes, `cpu MHz` is the current frequency of that core. 3.40GHz is the max freq specified by the manufacturer(Higher frequency can be achieved by overclocking).

Variation in operating frequency is known as CPU frequency scaling. It enables the operating system to scale the CPU frequency up or down in order to save power. CPU frequencies can be scaled automatically depending on the system load, in response to ACPI events, or manually by userspace programs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, my concern is how to get the TSC frequency. I made a simple program and I got 3502 MHz (aproximately), in the 3.4 GHz machine. So the Linux time() function is not very exact, or the TSC is faster than the claimed 3.4 GHz.

Comment: @SanketParmar note that on modern CPUs frequency scaling does not affect the frequency the TSC runs at (known as invariant TSC)